# C# system.speech.recognition alternate words

Tags: c#, speech-recognition, speech, speech-to-text

I am currently using the Microsoft.Speech API to dictate utterances into text, but what I really need is the alternative dictations the program could use. I am using this for my honours thesis, and for it I wish to know the top 10 interpretations of any utterance.

A very similar, if not exact question was asked in 2011:
[C# system.speech.recognition alternates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8214904/c-sharp-system-speech-recognition-alternates)

But was never answered. My question thus is: how does one get the alternatives to an interpretation of a dictation using the Microsoft.Speech API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.speech.recognition.recognitionresult.alternates%28v=office.14%29.aspx) handles what you're asking quite nicely. For reference, I'll post the included code. The final for loop is what contains the

```
// Handle the SpeechRecognized event. 
void SpeechRecognizedHandler(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
{
  //... Code handling the result

  // Display the recognition alternates for the result.
  foreach (RecognizedPhrase phrase in e.Result.Alternates)
  {
    Console.WriteLine(" alt({0}) {1}", phrase.Confidence, phrase.Text);
  }
}
```

The use of `e.Result.Alternates` is the official way to obtain other possible words.

If that isn't giving you enough results, [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.speech.recognition.speechrecognitionengine.updaterecognizersetting%28v=office.14%29.aspx) gives you the required information. You need to use `UpdateRecognizerSetting` on your `SpeechRecognitionEngine` to change the confidence rejection level. Setting it to 0 will make every single result display in `Alternates` along with the confidence levels, which you can sort to obtain the top 10.

Comment: Bear in mind that confidence levels are only loosely correlated with "correctness".  I built a system that highlighted low-confidence words in a recognition, only to find that there were plenty of low-confidence words that were correct, and, worse yet, a fair number of high-confidence words that were incorrect.  I ended up abandoning the project as it gave users a false sense of security.