# Always getting only one alternate for Windows Phone 8 speech recognition result?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, speech-recognition, dictation

I have a Windows Phone 8 app that uses speech recognition.  No matter what I try I always get exactly one Alternate guess and it's a duplicate of the main result text, despite asking for 10 alternates:

```
    // Get alternates, max 10.
    IEnumerable<SpeechRecognitionResult> iterSRR = srResult.GetAlternates(10);
    List<SpeechRecognitionResult> listAlternates = iterSRR == null ? null : iterSRR.ToList();
```

I am using the default dictation context (i.e. - I am *not* using/loading any Context Free Grammars) and I have been trying long phrases where I don't talk clearly, usually a sure-fire recipe for getting Alternates from a speech reco engine.  But still, no real Alternate guesses.

I found this SO post on Alternates:

[Microsoft Speech Recognition: Alternate results with confidence score?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18965286/microsoft-speech-recognition-alternate-results-with-confidence-score)

In that post the author sets the Confidence thresholds for rejecting guesses to 0 so that nothing is rejected.  However, the WP8 SpeechRecognizer class doesn't have any fields like that in its Settings property.

Why am I getting only one Alternate that is really not an Alternate at all and how can I get a set of real alternates?

Answer (score 0):

The Windows Phone 8 dictation recognizer is a network recognizer, and doesn't provide alternates via SAPI.  You'll need to use a context-free grammar to get alternates.